# Unexpected error during MassIndexer operation

Tags: hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search, hibernate-ogm

I am using the following code to create hibernate search index:

```
        OgmConfiguration cfgogm=new OgmConfiguration();
        cfgogm.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
        serviceregistry=new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(cfgogm.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry();
        sessionfactory=cfgogm.buildSessionFactory(serviceregistry);         
        Session session=sessionfactory.getCurrentSession();


        FullTextSession fullTextSession = Search.getFullTextSession(session);
        fullTextSession.createIndexer(User.class).startAndWait();
```

but i get thi sexception:

```
ERROR: HSEARCH000058: HSEARCH000116: Unexpected error during MassIndexer operation
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractStatementProxyHandler.<init>(AbstractStatementProxyHandler.java:57)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.PreparedStatementProxyHandler.<init>(PreparedStatementProxyHandler.java:50)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.ProxyBuilder.buildPreparedStatement(ProxyBuilder.java:187)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.ConnectionProxyHandler.postProcess(ConnectionProxyHandler.java:167)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.ConnectionProxyHandler.continueInvocation(ConnectionProxyHandler.java:139)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractProxyHandler.invoke(AbstractProxyHandler.java:81)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy17.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$5.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:147)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:166)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareQueryStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:145)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1720)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1697)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:832)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:293)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2382)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2368)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2198)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2193)
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(CriteriaLoader.java:122)
    at org.hibernate.internal.StatelessSessionImpl.list(StatelessSessionImpl.java:657)
    at org.hibernate.internal.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:374)
    at org.hibernate.internal.CriteriaImpl.uniqueResult(CriteriaImpl.java:396)
    at org.hibernate.search.batchindexing.impl.IdentifierProducer.loadAllIdentifiers(IdentifierProducer.java:130)
    at org.hibernate.search.batchindexing.impl.IdentifierProducer.inTransactionWrapper(IdentifierProducer.java:115)
    at org.hibernate.search.batchindexing.impl.IdentifierProducer.run(IdentifierProducer.java:96)
    at org.hibernate.search.batchindexing.impl.OptionallyWrapInJTATransaction.run(OptionallyWrapInJTATransaction.java:135)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

Aug 28, 2013 12:31:10 PM org.hibernate.search.impl.SimpleIndexingProgressMonitor indexingCompleted
INFO: HSEARCH000028: Reindexed 0 entities
```

I dont know exactly why I get this exeption?could you please help me to solve this problem